# Why is it only possible to `seek` from the beginning of a text file?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Python [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.2/tutorial/inputoutput.html#methods-of-file-objects) says:

> In text files (those opened without a `b` in the mode string), only
>   seeks relative to the beginning of the file are allowed (the exception
>   being seeking to the very file end with `seek(0, 2)`).

And indeed, this fails:

```
with open(filename, 'rt') as f:
    f.seek(2, os.SEEK_SET)
    f.seek(2, os.SEEK_CUR)

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 3, in <module>
io.UnsupportedOperation: can't do nonzero cur-relative seeks
```

**The Question**

I can easily replace every `f.seek(offset, os.SEEK_CUR)` with `f.seek(f.tell() + offset, os.SEEK_SET)`, so, why doesn't Python do it itself?

This works:

```
with open(filename, 'rt') as f:
    f.seek(2, os.SEEK_SET)
    f.seek(f.tell() + 2, os.SEEK_SET)
```

Am I missing something? Will this fail sometimes? What should I be careful about?

I can imagine problems with seeking into the middle of a multi-byte UTF-8 sequence, but I don't see how it makes a difference whether I seek from `SEEK_SET` or `SEEK_CUR`.

Comment: The [documentation for `TextIOBase.seek`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html#io.TextIOBase.seek) mentions that only an offset of 0 is allowed with `SEEK_CUR`, though again without providing a reason. (I only mention it because the tutorial would be a poor place to provide the only mention of this.)

Comment: The [documentation for `tell`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html#io.TextIOBase.tell) mentions that the position is an "opaque number", not necessarily related to the number of bytes in the underlying stream. It also says that the offset for `SEEK_SET` must be 0 or a value returned by `f.tell()`. I suspect the intent would be to ban an expression like `f.tell() + 2` as well, but the type system can't make the distinction.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suspect `f.seek(f.tell() + 2, os.SEEK_SET)` is only allowed because the implementation cannot distinguish this from `f.seek(f.tell(), os.SEEK_SET)`. From the [documentation for `seek`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html#io.TextIOBase.seek):

> SEEK_SET or 0: seek from the start of the stream (the default); offset must either be a number returned by TextIOBase.tell(), or zero. Any other offset value produces undefined behaviour.

Since `f.tell() + 2` isn't a value returned by `f.tell()`, that's undefined behavior, because you aren't supposed to know what the return value of `f.tell()` represents, and so adding 2 to it isn't meaningful.

The idea is that the *only* seeks allowed are to absolute positions you saved from previous calls to `f.tell()`, not arbitrarily calculated positions.

Comment: Although I am not sure, it looks reasonable to be like that, given the "opaque number" phrasing.

Comment: Yes, this explains it. It could have been made more explicit, by not using an integer for offset, but I guess they didn't want to break compatibility that way.